# Firestore query for document created by event listener returns undefined

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an event listener that creates a document in a collection called 'maxes' when there is a new document created in a collection called 'onboardings'. This 'onboardings' document is created by my front-end which is FlutterFlow:

```
exports.estFirst1RM = functions.firestore.document('/onboardings/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        bench1RM = calc1RM(snapshot.data().benchRiR, snapshot.data().benchReps, snapshot.data().benchLoad);
        uuid = snapshot.data().uuid
        //create new bench max doc
        newBenchMaxId = uuidv4();
        db.collection('maxes').doc(newBenchMaxId).set({
            load: bench1RM,
            createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
            maxType: 'bench',
            uuid: uuid,
            initial: true,
    });
```

I have a separate event listener that listens for when a new 'maxes' document is created in the above scenario and runs the following code in response:

```
async function getInitial1RM(maxType, uuid){
    maxDoc = await db.collection('maxes').where('maxType', '==', maxType).where('uuid', '==', uuid).get(); 
    if (!maxDoc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
      } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
      } 
    load = maxDoc.load;
    return load;
```

The issue I am having is that the value for 'load' returns undefined.

My hunch is that it is due to some kind of delay in creating the 'maxes' document, because the console log always returns 'No such document!' despite my having verified via console logs that I am passing the correct parameters for 'maxType' and 'uuid' in the getInitial1RM function.

Even more puzzling, I've noticed that these console logs do not appear immediately in my Google Cloud Functions console-- they are often delayed by 10-20 seconds. Not sure if this is related, but I am noting it here because the "delay" theme is suspicious.

I'm at a loss for what could be going on. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one extremely important piece of information to know: Cloud Functions triggers are not "listeners" (you will not see that term anyone in Cloud Functions documentation).  Cloud Functions are *triggers* that get invoked whenever an an event that matches the criteria reaches the product.  These events are not guaranteed to be invoked in particular order in relation to other triggers or other actual listeners in your app code, and they are not guaranteed to be delivered within any specific time. Your application code should never assume that they execute immediately.

If you want your app code to respond to some database change in a trigger, it should listen for that change and respond accordingly.

Also you should know that your Cloud Functions trigger code does not return a promise that resolves after all the async work is complete.  set() returns a promise, and you should return that from the function to let it know that the work is complete.

```
return db.collection('maxes').doc(newBenchMaxId).set({
    // ...
})
```

You should read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) about this to better understand the issue.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. After a few hours of debugging, I narrowed the issue down to a .get() query that was trying to query a 'maxes' document immediately after that 'maxes' document was supposed to have been created by the Firestore trigger. 

My guess is that because these events are not guaranteed to be delivered within any specific time, the get() query fails.